# Typescript - Argument of type 'HTMLTableRowElement | null is not assignable to parameter of type HTMLElement

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular application, I am trying to access the DOM to scroll a table row into view. For this purpose, I have created a method and pass in the following parameter:

```
this.scrollIntoView(this.tableElement?.rows.item(this.tableComponent.index));
```

Apparently the parameter can be null and undefined and I am getting the following typescript error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'HTMLTableRowElement | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
```

The method `scrollIntoView(row: HTMLElement)` accepts an HTMLElement as input. The `this.tableElement` is an `HTMLTableElement`.  And apparently the issue is that I pass in a row into `this.scrollintoView()` that could be null.

I have tried to avoid this issue by simply placing my method `this.scrollIntoView()` into an if-block, which checks if the parameter is null or undefined:

```
  if (
    this.tableElement?.rows.item(this.tableComponent.index) !== null &&
    this.tableElement?.rows.item(this.tableComponent.index) !== undefined
  ) {
```

Well. None of this helps. I don't know what the issue is and would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Can you show the function?

Comment: Try using non null assertion operator (!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message looks like a compiler message based on incorrect variable types, so I think the error occurs before your condition runs.

I suspect you have to do this:

`scrollIntoView(row: HTMLTableRowElement | null | undefined)`

And change the value you're passing into the function so that it isn't an HTMLTableElement.

This is a bit of a guess since you didn't tell us what `tableElement` is, nor did you share any code from your scroll method.

Answer (score 1):

I have to fight TypeScript on things like this a lot. I would usually do:

`this.scrollIntoView(this.tableElement?.rows.item(this.tableComponent.index) as HTMLTableRowElement);`